# IQueryFilter where Clause quering two feature class at a time

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, sql, query

I need to query two feature class at the same time using IQueryFIlter.

For eg -

FeatureClass -- A has field OBJECTID

FeatureClass -- B has field OBJECTID

what i am tring to do is --

```
IQueryFilter iqf = new QueryFilter();
iqf .setWhereClause(B+".OBJECTID = "+A+".OBJECTID");
IFeatureCursor resultCursor = B.search(iqf, false);
```

Is this possible , if yes what is the correct methord because currently i am facing error--

> "Too few parameters. Expected 1"

Might its not taking A.OBJECTID properly ////

Comment: Did you read [about joining tables in the online docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000002zw000000.htm)?

Comment: IQueryFilter isn't really designed to join tables.  For that you should be using a IQuerDef.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000146000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to do anything but the simplest queries in ArcObjects. Here is a method to create an in memory join between 2 tables.

```
public static ITable Join(string relationshipName, ITable tableA, ITable tableB, string tableAJoinField, string tableBJoinField, IQueryFilter queryF, string targetFields, esriJoinType joinType, esriRelCardinality cardinality)
        {
            IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory mrcFactory = new MemoryRelationshipClassFactoryClass();
            IRelationshipClass relationship = mrcFactory.Open(
                relationshipName,
                (IObjectClass)tableA, tableAJoinField,
                (IObjectClass)tableB, tableBJoinField,
                "forward", "backward",
                cardinality);

            // Open the RelQueryTable
            IRelQueryTableFactory rqtFactory = new RelQueryTableFactoryClass();

            bool joinForward = true;
            bool doNotPushJoinToDb = true;
            bool openAsLeftOuterJoin = (joinType == esriJoinType.esriLeftOuterJoin);

            IRelQueryTable relQueryTable = rqtFactory.Open(relationship, joinForward, queryF, null, targetFields, doNotPushJoinToDb, openAsLeftOuterJoin);
            ITable joinTable = relQueryTable as ITable;

            return joinTable;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot .Just waiting for some more suggetions , if not will mark yours as answer.////